# android app to track distance between two users

Tags: android, location, android-bluetooth

I have to develop a android application which alerts via beep or some sound, if current user is close proximity to other user (i.e. less than or equal to 3 meters). Could you suggest possible solution. Bluetooth could be one of the option but donot know if it allows to calculate distance.

Comment: "Could you suggest possible solution" -- generally speaking, there isn't one.

Comment: As mentioned, may be using bluetooth you can calculate distance by taking reference of RSSI(Received Signal strength indicator) indicator value. It can give you approximate distance, but it sometimes varies dramatically, if certain surface(like glass or wall) intervention in between of bluetooth.

Comment: Thank you Dhaval. Any reference sample code you have